# Find select knowing just part of its name

Tags: capybara

In Capybara, how can I refer to a select knowing only part of its name?

I have the following piece of HTML

```
<select name="user[work_hours][HASH][end_hour]">
 ...
</select>
```

Where HASH is an unknown value, and I need to find the select.
Can I use a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want. Depending on surrounding HTML you may be able to scope the find to a section of the page that only includes the one select so you don't need to specify anything to match the select at all

```
find('css to locate wrapping/scoping element').find(:select)
```

If that's not possible you can use CSS attribute begins-with and ends-with selectors like

```
find('select[name^="user[work_hours]["][name$="][end_hour]"]')
```

If that seems too complicated you can use the :element selector type which will allow you to match on any attribute with a string or regex. This may be inefficient on large pages with many select elements.

```
find(:element, :select, name: /user\[work_hours\]\[.*\]\[end_hour\]/
```

Another solution if the options in the select are unique on the page would just be to select the option and not worry about finding the actual select element

```
select('text of option')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How about if I need to expect the paage to have such field? `expect(page).to have_field(...)`.

Comment: @Sig it depends exactly what the ...  in have_field is  and what the HTML is for that field